# Showing visual component without reference on Context

Tags: android

I have my own implementation of PhoneStateListener

```
public class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private Context context;

    public PhoneCallListener(Context context)
    {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
            Log.i("PHONE_CALL", "Number: " + incomingNumber);

        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Somebody is calling!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

I want to show any visual component ie. Toast in code above. But I don't know why it doesn't show anything. Probably there will be something wrong with context, but it doesn't write any error. In LogCat there is correct writed incoming number, everything looks right but that Toast doesn't showed anytime..

Comment: did you put .show() after your toast

Comment: Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Somebody is calling!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Sorry guys! :)

Comment: glad to be of assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didnt put .show() on your toast for it to actually show

like this

```
Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Somebody is calling!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```